# Django Ajax Post - works sometimes

Tags: django, ajaxform

I have a Django application where I am using AJAX to do a post when submitting a form.  My issue is what do I set the URL to in my JavaScript?

JavaScript snippet:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "search/do_post/", // the endpoint
        type: "POST", // http method
        data : {
            relevancy: relevancy,
            report_id: report_id,
            query: query_text,
            //csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
```

urls.py snippet:

```
path("search/do_post/", do_post_view, name="do_post"),
```

My issue is that sometimes the above works and sometimes it does not.  When it doesn't I get:

> POST http://localhost:1227/search/search/do_post/ 404 (Not Found)

When I see that I then remove the search part from the url in my JavaScript. Sometimes that works and sometimes not.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with a leading slash to define an *absolute* path, otherwise the request is send to a path relative to the current one, so `/search` instead of <s>`search`</s>:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/search/do_post/",
    // …
},
```

you can also work with a [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) which is more convenient:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'do_post' %}",
    // …
},
```

Comment: I tried the second example and got this error: POST http://127.0.0.1:1227/search/%7B%%20url%20'do_post'%20%%7D 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: @PhilO: do you render this in the template? If it is a JavaScript file, then of course the template engine does not render. So the first one is for a separate JavaScript file, the second if it is "inline" JavaScript.